# RODBC sqlUpdate failed: Invalid character value for cast specification

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the console output after executing the sqlUpdate() function. As you can see, it fails at the first row of the data frame.

I suspect that the problem has to do with the `introduced_at` list component of my `Bills.df` data frame.

```
Bills.df$introduced_at <- as.Date(Bills.df$introduced_at, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Before this statement, `introduced_at` is of type `character`. But this changes it to `double`. I understand that this may have something to do with the R internals, since it uses C data types to store various R data structures. Maybe it's the wrong expression for data type conversion?

Additionally, if this is a `Date` type issue, I'd also like to know how to properly convert the `updated_at` type to Datetime to prevent a similar issue from occurring. The structure of `updated_at` is as follows: `2015-09-01T10:19:13-04:00`. I'm not comfortable with `as.POSIXlt` and `asPOSIXct` so I'm not sure which function is appropriate.

```
"updated_at": "2015-09-01T10:19:13-04:00"
```

Comment: It might be easier to make the updated_at column in the database a varchar and then do any date conversions after you update the table.

Comment: You just need to make the data types match between both systems. Dates can be tricky so you may want to convert it to character for the transition from R to T-SQL then change it as you like within SQL Server.